# Keep a user in a TEdit

Tags: firemonkey, setfocus

I have to check a value of TEdit->Text when a user leaves it and return him to the TEdit, if the value is wrong. The code below works nice in a VCL but it doesn't work in a FMX. So it beeps but doesn't return.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1Exit(TObject *Sender)
{
if (Edit1->Text != "123")
    {
    Beep();
    Edit1->SetFocus();
    }
}
```

It is in a simple form with 2 TEdits only. What I do wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: I don't use C++ with Firemonkey but I wonder if you might have an OnValidate or OnValidating event in which you could check for validity of the input before the user exits the control?

Comment: I already tried it with the same result. It seems, all these events are called **before** changing the focus. So, SetFocus() is applied to a control still having focus, but after exiting from the event handler focus is changing by a plan and I couldn't affect on this plan. Only a possibility I see is to add a message to a message queue which will proceed **after** an exit from the event handler. But I couldn't find an appropriate mechanism to do this... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide a solution in Delphi Firemonkey. Hopefully, the same principles apply in C++ Firemonkey. The following code replaces the invalid text in Edit1 with the word 'Invalid' and returns the focus to Edit1, with 'Invalid' selected ready for overtyping.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Validate(Sender: TObject; var Text: string);
begin
  if Text <> '123' then
  begin
    Text := 'Invalid';
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
         procedure
          begin
            Edit1.SetFocus;
          end);
      end).Start;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've translated it to C++ and it works! But I don't clearly understand why? What does the Synchronize method do? What it synchronize with what and which way?

Comment: I think the Synchronize method suspends the main thread while your thread modifies the user interface. My impression is that this is to prevent the main thread changing the user interface at the same time that your thread is changing it. Please don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Dmitry: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel my answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple program:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1Exit(TObject *Sender)
{
TThread::CreateAnonymousThread(
    [=]()
    {
    TThread::Synchronize (NULL, [=](){
        Memo1->Lines->Add("Edit1->SetFocus()");
        });
    })->Start();
Memo1->Lines->Add("Edit1 exit");
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit2Enter(TObject *Sender)
{
Memo1->Lines->Add("Edit2 enter");
}
```

There are three controls on a form: 2 TEdits and a TMemo1. When I run it and jump from the TEdit1 to the TEdit2, I have on the memo:

```
Edit1 exit
Edit2 enter
Edit1->SetFocus()
```

Without threads, I would have

```
Edit1->SetFocus()
Edit1 exit
Edit2 enter
```

With threads, but without Synchronize I have

```
Edit1 exit
Edit1->SetFocus()
Edit2 enter
```

So, what Synchronize() synchronizes with what stays unclear for me.